# Elasticsearch 5.3.3: filter docs with same value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I have next mapping:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "jobs": {
      "properties": {
        "bullets": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "description": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "title": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Bullets is array of 4 strings, description generates from bullets.

To get documents i use MTL query with document id:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "more_like_this": {
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "description"
            ],
            "like": [
              {
                "_index": "index_name",
                "_type": "jobs",
                "_id": "doc_id"
              }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": "30%"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But some documents have description, similar to document with id `doc_id` or similar description between themselves.

Is there any way to filter docs with similar description (make this field unique for every doc in result)?